# Call a php child file within another child file

Tags: php

I have a file a.php in home folder, two files b.php and c.php are in a child_folder.
The content of the three files are  below

```
a.php
<?php
require 'child_folder/b.php';
?>

b.php (within child folder)
<?php
require 'c.php';
require 'child/c.php';
?>

c.php (within child folder)
<?php
echo 'this is c file<br>';
?>
```

When i run a.php, it echoes the following output

> this is c file
>
> this is c file

what is the right way to call the file c with the file b, weather it should be called w.r.t a file or w.r.t b file..?

Comment: dont include the same file twice!

Comment: This looks like it's working, so I don't see what your question means. I also don't see why you'd structure code this way. As the complexity increases you're going to find nested `includes` like this become very troublesome.

Comment: Can't see how this would work, unless you've got a `child_folder/c.php` **AND** `child_folder/child/c.php`

Answer (score 0):

The best method for doing this is to give absolute path of the file in 'include'. This wont make any confusion with nested directories and you can also copy and paste it from file to file.

```
define("CURRENT_PATH", dirname(__FILE__));   // This defines the path as the directory the file is in.

include(CURRENT_PATH . "/path/to/file");
```